# from skrules import SkopeRules ImportError: cannot import name 'six'

Tags: python, import

I am able to pip install (pip install skope-rules) but not import skoperules used for interpretable ML applications (https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/skope-rules).

I am getting the following error:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'six'`

This has been documented as an issue here: https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/skope-rules/issues/41
However, the fix suggested (see code snippet below) does not work either:

`pip install git+https://github.com/csinva/interpretability-implementations-demos  from imodels import SkopeRules`

Any ideas on how to import skrules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
import six
import sys
sys.modules['sklearn.externals.six'] = six
from skrules import SkopeRules
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you Elya! Do you use SkopesRules much and do you like it?

Comment: Glad to help you! I used SkopeRules in one task, it really helped me to understand my clustering results.